# Merging several strings in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I have a large list of servernames.  Some names include an fqdn, some do not.

The list of individual strings looks something like this:

- serverA
- serverA.something.com
- serverA
- serverB
- serverB.something.com
- serverC
- serverD.something.com

I would like to analyze a group of individual strings like above and get back 4 results:

- serverA.something.com
- serverB.something.com
- serverC
- serverD.something.com

Essentially, if I have multiple entries for a server, I want to keep the longer one (to include the fqdn).  If no entries for a server include an fqdn, I want to keep only the server name.  I do not want any duplicates in my resultset.  Any advice would be approciated.

Comment: what is the regex you have tried ?

Comment: I don't have one.  This is a problem I don not know how to approach. I could easily strip away the fqdn and remove any duplicates.  The problem is keeping the fqdn.  Keep in mind my actual list includes 1000+ servers.

Comment: define "longer" more subdomains ? more letters ?

Comment: Longer refers to string length.  If I have more than one entry for a server and one is longer (includes fqdn) that is the one I need to keep.

Comment: @prufrock if you have a solution, please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give that a go, Works for me

```
<?php
$test = array();
$test[]="serverA";
$test[]="serverA.something.com";
$test[]="serverA";
$test[]="serverB";
$test[]="serverB.something.com";
$test[]="serverC";
$test[]="serverD.something.com";
sort($test);
$final = array();
$temp = "#";
for($i=0,$count = count($test);$i<$count;$i++){
    if(substr( $test[$i], 0, strlen($temp) ) == $temp)
        $temp = $test[$i];
    else {
    $final[] = $temp;
    $temp = $test[$i];
    }
}
//unset first 
unset($final[0]);
//add in last
$final[] = $temp;
var_dump($final);
?>
```

gives me this

```
array
  1 => string 'serverA.something.com' (length=21)
  2 => string 'serverB.something.com' (length=21)
  3 => string 'serverC' (length=7)
  4 => string 'serverD.something.com' (length=21)
```

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you have the list as an array of values in PHP. How you solve it is by using rsort. the first element is a kepper and you drop every element after that prefxies the last in your accumulator. TO get it in alphabetical order you sort the result after you've run it trough array_reduce.